# Execute a subroutine through parallel::ForkManager

Tags: perl

I am not able to get the desired result .I want to execute the sub routine my_fun in separate thread.but $meterId is not changing .Example if I execute 3 thread then $meterId is same like OSE-123,OSE123,OSE-123

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;
my $max_procs = 3;
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($max_procs);

NAMES:for (my $i= 0 ;$i <=$ENV{'NO_OF_CUSTOMER'};$i++)
{
my $pid = $pm->start() and next NAMES;
my_fun();

$pm->finish(); # pass an exit code to finish

}

sub my_fun()

{


$meterId='OSE-'.int (rand(10000000));
lock($meterId);
chomp (my $timeCheck=`date +%H`);
my $cmdOut= $testCaseObj->preprovisionAccount   ("CUS_P_EUR_STD","ACCEUR_STD", "$meterId", "P_EUR_STD", "GEN" , "EUR","DPL");
my ($topLAcc,$subId,$cusId) = $testCaseObj->getAccountDetails($cmdOut);
$testCaseObj->updateLogTable("$cusId","$topLAcc","$subId","$meterId");

}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: [`lock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lock.html) _... If you are not under use threads::shared this does nothing._

Comment: Furthermore, P::FM creates processes, not threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you `fork` a process, it makes a copy of the process. That includes the seed of the random number generated. You'll need to [change the seed](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) in the child process.

```
my $pid = $pm->start() and next;

srand();
my_fun();

$pm->finish();
```